# Django REST and ModelViewSet filtering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I was previously using APIViews such as the following:

views.py

```
class AllProgramsApi(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        user = self.request.user
        userprograms = Program.objects.filter(user=user)
        serializer = ProgramSerializer(userprograms, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

here's my model:

```
class Program(models.Model):

    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cycles = models.ManyToManyField(Cycle)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default="False")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('programs:program', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_name
```

Now I've discovered ModelViewSet, which looks very convenient, but I can't seem to be able to filter for the user as I was previously doing in the APIView.

my attempt at views.py with ModelViewSet is the following and it works but I get all the content and not just the content related to a single user.

```
class AllProgramsApi(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProgramSerializer
    queryset = Program.objects.all()
```

How can I tweak the ModelViewSet so that it displays only the content related to the user who sends the request? What is the best method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use **get queryset** method,if you know more refer the doc [Filtering against the current user](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

```
class AllProgramsApi(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProgramSerializer
    queryset = Program.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        query_set = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return query_set
```

Answer (score 1):

there are permission_classes in django you can add permissions as per your requirements or you can create custom permissions

you would get better idea from [django permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

or you can create your queryset by defining get_queryset  method.