# Django rest ModelViewSet filtering objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models: Library and a Book. A Library will have Many Books.

```
class Library(models.Model):
    library_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # A library has many books
    which_library = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reader = models.ManyToManyField('Reader', related_name='wishlist')
```

my serializers:

```
class LibrarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Library
        fields = '__all__'

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    wishlist = ReaderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

And my view:

```
class LibraryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Library.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LibrarySerializer

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(which_library=library_id)
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

My Urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'libraries', LibraryViewSet)
router.register(r'books/(?P<library_id>[0-9]+)', BookViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

my Library routes work correct. However for Books, I need to return the books only belonging to specific library. The default URL and all() returns all the books in database and can retrieve single by hitting `books/1`.

How can I achieve this? I could do it previously with :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def books(request, library_id):
```

but now I want to do it with ModelViewSet.

Comment: A more general answer for arbitrary filtering is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323417/django-rest-and-modelviewset-filtering

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override `get_queryset` method of you viewset where you can define to return specific books. This works like this.

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = LibrarySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        books = Book.objects.filter(which_library=self.kwargs['library_id'])
        return books
```

You can also define `list` and `detail` methods where you can define your custom queries for Books. This is shown [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets).

Base name should be set like this.

```
router.register(r'books/(?P<library_id>[0-9]+)', BookViewSet, base_name='books')
```

Comment: first it throws could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute. error. If I add queryset = Book.objects.all() then it throws global name 'library_id' is not defined error

Comment: `get_queryset` is builtin function of ModelViewSet. You can see this in docs. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: I see here (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) that I have to register some base_name with router, but I do not get exactly how

Comment: It should be set in your routers. See updated answer

Comment: And where do I pass library_id param?

Comment: In `get_queryset` method, your kwargs will be available in `self.kwargs`. You are passing `library_id` in your urls, it will be in kwargs.

Comment: It did work! Thanks! Just one question: which is better approach? Using get_queryset() as you showed or using @detail_route(methods=['GET']) as pointed in first answer

Comment: I will not totally reject other approach but `get_queryset` give you short solution but other gives you more freedom over what your want to return and validation of parameters.

Comment: Thanks! And how could I retrieve query params like api/books/2?status=Available to filter further?

Comment: query parameters can be get from self.request.GET

Answer (score 1):

You can add `detail_route` to Library vewset:

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'])
def books_list(self, request, pk=None):
    library = self.get_object()   
    books = library.books.all()
    serializer = serializers.BookSerializer(books, many=True)
    response = Response(serializer.data)
    return response
```

now library's books should be listed with this url `libraries/{libriry_id}/books_list`.

Comment: So is it not possible with only ModelViewSet? I already had @api_view but I thought using ModelViewSet will reduce my code

Comment: @Nitish `detail_route` is part of ModelViewSet, it is just additional method that you are adding to the class.

Comment: @Nitish check full example here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: Do I have two separate URLs like books/ and books/<library_id> or only later is enough? Because right now I am getting in my Swagger options like /api/books/{library_id}/{book_id}/books_list/ or /api/books/{library_id}/{book_id}/ or /api/books/{library_id}/ for GET